# Check if ALL values of an array are under a particular number

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, ecmascript-5

I have a form where the user needs to put in all the people who are attending:

**Person 1**
Name
DOB
Email

**Person 2**
Name
DOB
Email

I need to work out each person's age and make sure at least one person is over the age of 16 to attend.

I get all the date of birth select field years and do the calculations to return each person's age.

I can then do an if statement `age <= 16` to return if the argument is true or not.

My issue is here.

I need to check if **ALL** people are under 16, not single items.

Basically, if ALL people are under the age of 16 display an alert else if one person is over 16 don't do anything.

I don't know if I can expand on what I have to achieve this or to do some type of array mapping? I have looked at array mapping but not with the added age calculation I need to do.

Your help/advice is greatly appreciated (ES5 below please).

```
const checkAllAges = document.querySelectorAll("[data-dob='dobYear']");

   function checkAge() {

       for (const item of Array.from(checkAllAges)) {
           const selectedYearValue = item.value;
           const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
           const age = currentYear - selectedYearValue;

           console.log(item)
           console.log(age)

           if(age <= 16) {
               console.log("one of the values is less than 16");
           }

           if(age > 16) {
               console.log("one of the values is greater than 16");
           }
       }
   }

   for (const item of Array.from(checkAllAges)) {
       item.onchange = function(){
           checkAge();
       };
   }
```

Below is what my console returns from "item","age" and age check if that helps:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help. Replace you code with this sample:

```
    const checkAllAges = document.querySelectorAll("[data-dob='dobYear']");
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

    if (Array.from(checkAllAges).every(({ value }) => (value - currentYear) < 16)) {
      console.log('Everyone is under 16');
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

or

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

```js
let isUnder16 = Array.from(ages).every(function(age) {
  return age < 16;
});
```

```js
let isBigger16 = Array.from(ages).some(function(age) {
  return age > 16;
});
```

Comment: Looks good, but if you are going to put it in a snippet I recommend including the pertinent inputs so that it can run and log a result.